# Even setting random seed sequential model in keras returns differnt results

Tags: machine-learning, keras, keras-layer, random-seed

Can anyone help me to understand why this model does not give reproducible results? It changes the accuracy values for test sets and other validation sets I am using, each time I run it. I am using a defined seed. I can not understand why that is happening.

Below is part of my code:

```
np.random.seed(7)

# Create the model
def create_model(neurons=190, init_mode='normal', activation='relu', inputDim=8040, dropout_rate=0.8,
                 learn_rate=0.001, momentum=0.7, weight_constraint=5): 
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(neurons, input_dim=inputDim, kernel_initializer=init_mode, activation=activation, kernel_constraint=maxnorm(weight_constraint), kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.002)))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    optimizer = RMSprop(lr=learn_rate)

    # compile model

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='RmSprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

model = create_model()

seed = 7
# Define k-fold cross validation test harness

kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
cvscores = []
for train, test in kfold.split(X_train, Y_train):
    print("TRAIN:", train, "VALIDATION:", test)


# Fit the model

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=40, batch_size=50, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), verbose=0)
```

I would appreciate some comments on it.

Answer (score 1):

Your random seed is fixing your cross-validation split but not the model weight initialization, which you specify in `create_model` when you set keyword "init_mode=normal".

You could try setting the RNG seed prior to calling `create_model` but depending on how keras is generating its random numbers, you may need to resort to using a [custom initializer](https://keras.io/initializers/#using-custom-initializers) to get consistent results.

Seed configuration is dependent on several other factors, including which keras backend you are using (Theano vs. TensorFlow) and which python version you are using. See [this github issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2280) for additional details.

Comment: I did not get what do you mean by setting the RNG seed. By the way `random_state` is not a function or attribute of create model, so I do not know how to set a seed there then. Using that custom initializer, does it mean I have to exclude my `init_mode='normal'` and that one proosed by the keras documentaiton you sent me the link?

Comment: I have tried this: `from keras import backend as K

def my_init(shape, dtype=None):
    return K.random_normal(shape, dtype=dtype, seed=7)

def create_model(neurons=190, init_mode='normal', activation='relu', inputDim=8040, dropout_rate=0.8,
                 learn_rate=0.001, momentum=0.7, weight_constraint=5): 
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(neurons, input_dim=inputDim, kernel_initializer=my_init, activation=activation, kernel_constraint=maxnorm(weight_constraint), kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.002)))` but still returns me different results.

Comment: My point was that there we random numbers being drawn even before you set the random seed. See the update to my answer for additional details.